# How can I synchronize a child kernel inside a parent kernel safely without affecting the performance?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a parent kernel than calls a child kernel as shown below. How can I make sure that the child kernel completed all its threads' calculations before continuing in the parent's calculations?

I know that I can't use `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` inside parent kernel as it may result in problems. What can I do?

```
__device__ void child(double* A, double* B, int p)
{
    int r;
    r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    B[p + r] += A[r];
}

__global__ void parent(double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
    int i, r;
    r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    child<<<1, 5>>>(A, B, 7 * r);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        C[r] += B[r * 7 + i];
}

int main()
{
    parent<<<1, 2>>>(A, B, C);
}
```

Comment: you can use stream semantics as indicated [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudadevicesynchronize-from-device-code-is-deprecated/215900/4), however this does not allow you to see the results of a child kernel in that child's parent kernel.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I need the values calculated by the child kernel in the calculation of the parent kernel. What should I do?

Comment: Either use the potentially deprecated `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` or refactor your code to not require that (for example using multiple kernel launches).  It's possible that new methodology will be part of some future CUDA toolkit, but at the moment those are the only options I am aware of.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you. I think I will go for the second option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Robert Crovella's comment, it seems the best solution now is to refactor the code to avoid any unpredictable results like this:

```
__global__ void child(double* A, double* B)
{
    int r, c;
    r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    B[7 * r + c] += A[c];
}

__global__ void parent(double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
    int i, r;
    r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        C[r] += B[r * 7 + i];
}

int main()
{
    dim3 Grid(1, 1);
    dim3 Block(2, 5);
    child<<<Grid, Block>>>(A, B);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    parent<<<1, 2>>>(A, B, C);
}
```